# How python file objects are managed?

Tags: python, file

I think we can work with files in two ways: directly with the kernel (as a file's descriptor) and with pointers (on high level languages as C).

So, are files managed the same way in Python (like files pointer as in C for example)?
Do we create a pointer to a file when using open() function in Python?.

Comment: You're asking about Python and calling *C* a high-level language?

Answer (score 4):

In UNIX-derived or POSIX-compatible environments, all file I/O goes through "*file descriptors*". File descriptors are small integers that are passed to various OS system calls. They are designed to be "*opaque handles*"; they mean nothing in themselves, they only exist to be passed to file I/O system calls.

Many languages implement value-add libraries to do advanced file I/O beyond the simple open/close/read/write/seek that the kernel provides. In C, that library is described by `#include <stdio.h>`. The associated data structure is a `FILE*` (a typedef of a pointer to some kind of struct). Given the requirements of the first paragraph, we can see that a `FILE*` must somehow internally store a file descriptor.

It is not helpful to say that C I/O goes through pointers. C programs never directly examine a `FILE`. Rather, the `FILE*` is used as an opaque handle and is passed to various library calls.

In Python, the data structure is the built-in type `file`. Similarly, if `file` is to ever interact with the OS, it too must store a file descriptor.

It is an implementation detail, and not worthy of consideration, if Python's `file` is internally implemented via the `FILE*` mechanism, via some other value-add library, or directly via file descriptors. All that we know for sure is that, on POSIX, `file.write(python_buffer)` must eventually become a system call like `write(file_descriptor, buffer, len)`.

As to your specific question, "Do we create a pointer to a file when using open() function in Python?", the question is vague because "pointer to a file" is not a particularly meaningful phrase. If you meant "Does the interpreter call `fopen()` to create a `FILE*`?", then the answer is "Maybe. Who cares?"

What *is* true, and what is important to know is that when we call the `open()` built-in function in Python, it returns a Python object of type `file`. That `file` objects allow for certain file I/O operations.